# Sparkjava with a Jetty returns 404

Tags: angularjs, xml, jetty, spark-java

I'm trying to run a single page web application written in angularjs with spark java on a jetty, the project is written in eclipse kepler as a Maven project. 
the error I'm receiving when I go into the url http://localhost:8085/ is as follows, and it doesnt matter if I try to access any other url's or point directly to the index.html/jsp still gets the same error.

HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /. Reason: 
Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

Eclipse Console is showing that the server is up and running

> == Spark has ignited ...
>     Listening on localhost:8085 [Thread-2] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.0.2.v20130417 [Thread-2]
>    INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started
>   ServerConnector@12ee37d9{HTTP/1.1}{localhost:8085}

Added the Package Explorer in case that might help.

[image]

I'll add some of the files code and if move is needed just let me know and ill edit to add them.

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>todoapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>todoapp1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.2.v20130417</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/public</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.todoapp.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Bootstrap.java**

```
    package com.todoapp;

import com.mongodb.*;

import static spark.Spark.setIpAddress;
import static spark.Spark.setPort;
import static spark.SparkBase.staticFileLocation;

public class Bootstrap {
    private static final String IP_ADDRESS = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP") != null ? System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP") : "localhost";
    private static final int PORT = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP") != null ? Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP")) : 8085;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        setIpAddress(IP_ADDRESS);
        setPort(PORT);
        staticFileLocation("/public");
        new TodoResource(new TodoService(mongo()));
    }

    private static DB mongo() throws Exception {
        String host = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST");
        if (host == null) {
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");
            return mongoClient.getDB("todoapp");
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT"));
        String dbname = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME");
        String username = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME");
        String password = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD");
        MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectionsPerHost(20).build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), mongoClientOptions);
        mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB(dbname);
        if (db.authenticate(username, password.toCharArray())) {
            return db;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not able to authenticate with MongoDB");
        }
    }
}
```

this 2 files are the ones responsible for the jetty server, now I have been researching the internet for over a day now trying to find solution and reasons for this error, but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `/public` directory, where your html files land, is accessible through your project's classpath. In order to test this, try using [staticFiles.externalLocation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#static-files) (this for version 2.5, `externalStaticFileLocation` in your case) with the full path to `/public` as the param. If it works, you'd probably move your `/public` directory to the same location as your java packages and it will work with `staticFileLocation("/public")` as you expect.